# Behavior of the gyroscopic effect from different materials

Tags: gyroscopes, spin-statistics

Are there any experiments of the gyroscopic effect from different materials? Especially from materials with equally distributed intrinsic spin of the protons, neutrons and electrons. Magnesium seems to be such a material (not sure).

Comment: It should be clear that any material that could exhibit different properties from "ordinary" material when made into a gryoscope would exhibit a non-negligible gyroscopic property when *not* formed into a macroscopic gyroscope.

Comment: @dmckee Could you be more specific, please.